# Why is this type of C99 struct initialisation not allowed?

Tags: c, struct, initialization

Why is this type of C99 struct initialisation not allowed?  If (not) possible, please explain.

```
struct Point {int x; int y;};
struct Data {struct Point p;};
struct Data data = {0};
data.p = {.x = 2, .y = 4};
```

However, this is allowed:

```
struct Point {int x; int y;};
struct Data {struct Point p;};
struct Data data = {0};
struct Point p = {.x = 2, .y = 4};
data.p = p;
```

Edit: `data = {}` -> `data = {0}`

Comment: Neither is allowed in strictly conforming C; the grammar requires that there be at least one initializer, so `struct Data data = {};` is incorrect.

Comment: `data.p = {.x = 2, .y = 4};` is an assignment, not initialization. In the standard C grammar, the right operand of an assignment must be an expression (particularly an *assignment-expression*). `{.x = 2, .y = 4}` is not an expression; there is no expression that starts with `{`. `p` is an expression, so it can be the right operand of an assignment. You can use `data.p = (struct Point) {.x = 2, .y = 4};`. `(struct Point) {.x = 2, .y = 4}` is a compound literal, which does form an expression.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, Those two comments could be posted as an answer as-is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither code sample is allowed in strictly conforming C; the grammar requires that there be at least one initializer inside the braces, so `struct Data data = {}`; is incorrect. (It can be corrected to `struct Data data;` or `struct Data data = {0};`.)

`data.p = {.x = 2, .y = 4};` is an assignment, not initialization. In the standard C grammar, the right operand of an assignment must be an expression (specifically an *assignment-expression*). The source code `{.x = 2, .y = 4}` is not an expression; there is no expression that starts with `{`. The source code `p` is an expression, so it can be the right operand of an assignment.

You can use `data.p = (struct Point) {.x = 2, .y = 4};`. In this , `(struct Point) {.x = 2, .y = 4}` is a compound literal, which does form an expression.

Comment: (1) Point taken about `data = {}` vs `data = {0}`.  I made an edit on my question.
(2) Thank you to clarify about assignment vs initialization.  That explains my misunderstanding.